# Can anyone identify the brand of this bathroom sink faucet?

Tags: bathroom, shower, faucet

I wanted to replace this faucet and had a hard time figuring out what brand it is. Does anyone know what company this is?

[image: faucet]

[image: faucet]

Comment: What country was it purchased in?

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but why do you care what brand the faucet was? Any 8" spread (well, variable spread, properly speaking) faucet will fill the 3 holes in your sink. (I apologize if you're just trying to find parts to fix your existing faucet. In that case, take the parts to a plumbing supplier.)

Comment: Every sink in my household has the same faucet. I don't want this one sink to have a different designed faucet.

Comment: This is a good one. I don't recognize it, and the best I could find online was another person with the same question about the same logo: [Identifying Part mfg from logo 1991](http://www.plumbingzone.com/f7/identifying-part-mfg-logo-1991-a-735/) and [Identifying a 1991 parts manufacturer from logo](http://www.plbg.com/forum/read.php?1,380006). Unfortunately, they didn't get an answer either. I even tried a Google reverse image lookup for the logo... no luck.

Answer (score 6):

RUBINET is the brand. They're a Canadian company in Vaughn.

I work in the industry where I see faucets like this time to time. This is an older faucet that is at least 20 years old, so you won't find it on their website.

Comment: @user167119 You're right, I've seen this brand before doing a remodel but was unsure of the model, I reached out to their support team and this was their response: *Yes, this is a very old faucet from the 90’s called the Master series. It has been discontinued from 1999.* Feel free to include this in your answer.